# Do monsters ever use player abilities?

Tags: diablo-iii

Sometimes when playing with a Wizard friend I see meteors that seem to be targeting me instead of monsters. I'm not even sure they are using meteor in the first place! With all the chaos of battle it is hard to tell where damage is coming from.

Do monsters have any abilities that share artwork with player abilities that need to be avoided? Or can I safely assume all meteors (and other player abilities) are safe to stand in?

Comment: If you're in Act IV, keep an eye on the skies, because those meteors *hurt*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some monster types do indeed launch meteors at you.

Skills I've seen monsters use:

- Meteor (some monster types)
- Teleport (Teleporter uniques, some monster types)
- Mirror image (Illusionist uniques)
- Shock Pulse (Electrified uniques)
- Slow Time (Zoltun Kulle)

Comment: Not to forget the mirror image monsters...

Comment: @cedi good point, added

Comment: Also barbarian shouts can be used by enemies.